# dynamic import uneven data neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a small txt file (200-300 entries) of filePaths and fileNames on a given system:

```
~/a/aa/text.txt
~/a/ab/text.txt
~/b/x/y/text.txt
~/b/x/xx/y/yy/z/text.txt
```

I know that data can be imported into neo4j as a csv, so I could replace the slashes for commas in those strings to get columns and import the file.

The problem is that there is an uneven number of columns, so it would give the error `"Cannot merge node using null property value for"`, is there a way to import this kind of thing in Neo4j? Basically what I'm trying to get is a tree from root to files.

The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) doesn't mention something like this.

Comment: If there is a subfolder `aa` inside `b` do you want to treat it as similar to subfolder `aa` inside `a` or they should be treated differently?

Comment: It should be treated different if they don't have the same "parent" node

Comment: I wish there was a way people won't fear to share their code. have you make sure you are not doing this? https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-cannot-merge-node-using-null-property-value/

Comment: The problem with that example is that there is a fixed number of columns, in this case the number of columns is variable so you can't access a specific property since you wouldn't know the value / name.